# Problems deriving the Quantum Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers, semiclassical

This is my first question at Physics SE so please be kind. I am well versed in the etiquette over at [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/553081/k-defaoite), but not so much here. Anyway, I thought this question was better suited to this site because it is less a problem of understanding mathematical computations and more of a problem about understanding why two results should be the same.

## MY QUESTION:

I am taking a quantum mechanics class and I have been given an assignment. It is as follows:

> Let $\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)$ be the wavefunction for a single particle satisfying Schrodinger's equation,
> $$i\hbar \partial_t\Psi=\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V\right)\Psi$$
> Write $\Psi$ in polar form, $\Psi=Re^{i\Theta}$. Show that:
> $$\partial_t R+\frac{\hbar}{2mR}\nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(R^2\nabla\Theta\right)=0$$
> Define $S=\hbar \Theta$. Show that $S$ satisfies the Quantum Hamilton-Jacobi equation:
> $$\partial_t S+\frac{\Vert\nabla S\Vert^2}{2m}+V=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2S.$$

After some lengthy calculations taking the time derivative and Laplacian of a composite function, I ended up with a big equation
$$i\hbar \partial _{t} R-\hbar R\partial _{t} \Theta =\frac{-\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\left( \nabla ^{2} R+i R\nabla ^{2} \Theta -R\Vert \nabla \Theta \Vert ^{2} +2i \nabla R\boldsymbol{\cdot } \nabla \Theta \right) +VR.$$
Taking the Imaginary part of both sides of the equation, we do end up with the first of the required equations
$$\partial _{t} R+\frac{\hbar }{2mR} \nabla \boldsymbol{\cdot }\left( R^{2} \nabla \Theta \right) =0$$
However taking the real part, we do not get the equation my professor wants. We instead get (using $S=\hbar \theta$)
$$\partial _{t} S+\frac{\Vert \nabla S\Vert ^{2}}{2m} +V=\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\frac{\nabla ^{2} R}{R}.$$

So... is my professor wrong? My results agree with [this other Physics SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270309/). If my professor **isnt't** wrong, can anyone explain why
$$\hbar \frac{\nabla^2 R}{R}=i\nabla^2S~?$$
Might be true?

Comment: Yes, OP's QHJE is correct, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_potential#Quantum_Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation). Related: [Madelung equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself. If we write
$$\Psi=e^Z$$
Where $Z$ is now allowed to be *complex*, we get
$$i \hbar \partial _{t} Z=\frac{-\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\left( \nabla ^{2} Z+\Vert \nabla Z\Vert ^{2}\right) +U$$
Letting $Z=\frac{iS}{\hbar}$ will yield the desired result.